# Adding args to multitheading

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, image-processing

I've created a pipeline for image rotation using OpenCV, and another function to apply multithreading to the pipeline.

The pipeline:

```py
def rotation_pipeline(img, rotation):
    
    # Rotation options
    rotation_options = {
        '90':cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE,
        '180':cv2.ROTATE_180,
        '270':cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE
    }
    
    # Rotate single image
    img_name = img.split('/')[-1]
    read_image = cv2.imread(img)
    rotated_image = cv2.rotate(read_image, rotation_options[rotation])
    cv2.imwrite(f'../processed_data/jpeg/augmented/{rotation}_degree_{img_name}', rotated_image)
    print(f'{img_name} rotated {rotation} degrees.')
```

And the multithreading function:

```py
# Rotations
def rotate_images(rotation):
    '''
    Options for `rotation` are '90', '180', and '270'.
    '''   
    # Read in metadata
    PATH = '../data/jpeg/train/'
    df = pd.read_csv('../data/train.csv')
    augmentation_df = df[df['target'] == 1]
        
    # Obtain image names
    melanoma_names = augmentation_df['image_name'].values
    image_paths = PATH + melanoma_names + '.jpg'

    # Create new metadata
    augmentation_df['image_name'] = augmentation_df['image_name'].map(lambda x: f'{rotation}_degree_'+x)
 
    # Multithread rotations
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(rotation_pipeline, image_paths, ('rotation',rotation))
    
    # Add metadata to csv
    if 'augmented_metadata.csv' in os.listdir('../processed_data/'):
        augmented_csv = pd.read_csv('../processed_data/augmented_metadata.csv')
        augmentation_df = pd.concat([augmented_csv, augmentation_df], axis=0)
    augmentation_df.to_csv('../processed_data/augmented_metadata.csv')
```

The code is designed to be included in my preprocessing pipeline as follows:

```py
rotate_images('90')
rotate_images('180')
rotate_images('270')
```

I've tested the code in a notebook, with `rotate_melanoma_images('90')`. But this only runs a single image. I've checked the output directory and confirmed that only a single image is rotated.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map),

> With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

I'm assuming that the reason why only one item is being run is because there is a single arg, and so the "shortest iterable is exhausted." That being said, it seems reasonable that there is a way to add args to a function using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` for *every* item in a list. I haven't been able to find anything online explaining how to do this, though--does anyone know how this works?

Comment: better use `print()` to see what you have in variable. Espsecially `image_paths`. Maybe you have only one file in this variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if you run `map()` in correct way. It may need `map( function, [(img1, rotate), (img2, rotate), (img3, rotate), etc.])`.

Comment: @furas I've checked every step with `print()`, and everything checks out in each function prior to the multithread mapping.

Comment: and what did you get in `image_paths` ? And what did you get in `rotation_pipeline()` ?

Comment: I'm not sure but if `map()` has argument `('rotation',rotation)` then it may runs it only two times because there are only two elements. It would have the same number of elements on this list as number of imags. And it will get from both list elements to create pairs `(img1, rotate), (img2, rotate), (img3, rotate), etc.`

Comment: @furas Curiously, after adding `args = [('rotation', rotation) for image in image_paths]` and replacing the `args` in the `map`, it still only operates on the first item--it just takes a couple of seconds longer now.

Comment: @furas I've additionally tried `args = [('img', image, 'rotation', rotation) for image in image_paths]`, to similar effect.

Comment: I can't run it so I can't see how it behave - and I don't have other ideas. My only idea was that `image_paths` has only one filename

Comment: @furas No, I confirmed that `len(image_paths)` is of size `augmentation_df.shape[0]`. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: @furas It appears that you were right, but for some reason the arg couldn't be named: `args = [rotation for image in image_paths]` and `executor.map(rotation_pipeline, image_paths, args)` seem to have done the trick.